# The commands I type after the if command in python do not work

Tags: python

I wrote what should show if 2 is called in the if command in Python, but it doesn't work.

```py
if baslangic == 2:
    print("meslekler:",meslekler)
```

Comment: Can you show the rest of your code?

Comment: To debug this sort of thing, don’t hesitate to print the value and type of baslangic before. Best guess is that it doesn't equals 2 as an int (either other value, either string)

Comment: If you're using `input` to read in the value of `baslangic`, it will be a string by default. Comparing a string to a an integer will never be True, so you'll have to convert them to the same format. Either use `int(input('Foo? '))` to convert the input to an int, or compare it to a string: `if baslangic == '2':`

Comment: https://i.hizliresim.com/lq5wzjh.PNG

Comment: Please don't include code as images (neither in the comments or in the post itself). Images are not searchable, do not have proper accessibility, can't be copy/pasted and makes it hard to follow the logic when they're hosted externally. That being said, the problem is what i mentioned in the comment.

Answer (score 1):

When you're using input to read in the value of baslangic, it will be a string by default.

Comparing a string to a an integer will never be True (`'2'` vs `2` - one is a numeric value, the other is a sequence of characters), so you'll have to convert them to the same format.

Either use `int(input('Foo? '))` to convert the input to an int when you read it (if the user is only expected to type in an integer), or compare it to a string:

```
if baslangic == '2':
```